# Prime numbers list generator immediately closing when run

Tags: python, primes

I'm trying to make a list of prime numbers.

```
primes = []
num=int
for num in range (2,100):
    for x in range (2, num):
        if (num % x) == 0:
            pass
        else:
            primes.append(num)
            break
print(primes)
input()
```

but it closes immediately when I try to open the .py file. I think there is a problem with the code.

Comment: hmm... I can't seem to reproduce this problem. It opens fine for me. What is your python version?

Comment: Are you just double clicking the .py file?

Comment: I finally run it but this time it listed all the numbers between [3-99]

Comment: Don't change the topic of your question. New topic -> new question.

Comment: What is `num=int` line for?

Comment: I think what OP was thinking was that `pass` is the same as `continue`. Probably came from a different language. It should be `continue` since a divisor was found for `num`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code executes and finishes, but it does not compute a list of prime numbers because it contains an error:

When you test each `num` to see if it's prime, you can test all possible divisors (as you try to do) and quit if you find a single divisor. If no divisor has been found when you've tested them all, only then add your number to the list

also, the line `num=int` is not needed

```
primes = []

for num in range (2,100):
    is_prime=True
    for x in range (2, num):
        if (num % x) == 0:
            is_prime=False
            break
    if is_prime:
       primes.append(num)

print(primes)
input()
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your if-else is incorrect.

If you get a "clean modulo" in your if block, what do you want to happen?  Hint:  not `pass`.

Second, when do you want to append to your prime list?

Not being too specific here as we shouldn't be doing this H/W assignment for you.  :)

Comment: The question was rolled back to it's original form, so this doesn't answer correctly anymore.